# PHP - Customize .zip File Before Download?

Tags: php, download, customization

So I am making a script where I want to learn how to limit use on one domain, but I need to modify the script before the download. My question is, I want to take a $_GET variable filled out by the user of their website. Customize a script with file_put_contents or something, and then download the modified script.. How would I go about this? Does it require Javascript and PHP, or just Javascript? I'm not sure how to go about it. An example of modifying a download can be found [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php)

Comment: Honestly, I just sat thinking about it for a good 30 minutes and had no direction.

Comment: What do you mean by download it?

Comment: @Tivie Sorry, fixed my explanation "Customize a script with file_put_contents or something, and then download the modified script."

Comment: so basically you want to create a DRM system so your script can't be shared by anyone except whoever you've sold it to? Good luck.. it's pretty much impossible to do such a thing securely with PHP.

Comment: @MarcB Well thats besides the point, I was just more or less giving an example of me modifying a script before download.

Comment: @MarcB "it's pretty much impossible to do such a thing securely with $anyLanguage

Comment: @necro: php  is just text. e.g. trivial to modify.

Comment: @MarcB I'd appreciate that in depth a bit more please. What steps do I take? Thats the question.

Comment: @MarcB I must be very dense but how the heck did you realize, from this question, the OP wanted a DRM system?!

Comment: what kind is that file ?

Comment: @Osa the download I'm trying to allow download? A .zip was what I had in mind.

Comment: If the file is on your server, and file is transferred through the php file, technically you can do it. Text files and images can be modified by php. For the rest, you will need some external libraries (for video for example).

Comment: From what i understood, you want to modify that zip file and append the domain name from $_GET to it before they download? if so.. why ? i'm a bit confused here.. What is the target from this at first place? put more explanation please

Comment: Modify a file inside of a download where it takes an untouched version of the download files, modifies a script INSIDE the download files by placing a $_GET variable, then zips it up, and pushes the headers to download it. Thats all I have so far on how I want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I understood correctly, a user fill some form with a var (lets call it $var) and clicks the form's submit button to download a file (lets call it 'myscript.php').

You want to edit 'myscript.php' and put the $var inside that script before the user downloads it. Is this assumption correct?

For that you need to prepare your script beforehand by placing a placeholder somewhere and then, before the user downloads the file, you change the placeholder for the intended block of code. Alternatively you can replace the first `<?php` tag for your code, if that's relevant.

Mini Example:

***myscript1.php***

```
<?php
$varb = 'a string with DEFAULT VAR inside just to test';
//Block of code goes here
//{%%DEFAULT VAR%%}
print $var;
```

***Code called by form:***

```
<?php
$path = 'myscript1.php';
$file = file_get_contents($path);
$var = $_GET['var'];
$block = '
    // valid php code that you put inside script (without <?php)
    // Alternatively you can grab the block of code
    // from a file with file_get_contents
    $var = ' . $var . ';';
$file = str_replace('//{%%DEFAULT VAR%%}', $var, $file);
```

---

Here's a more complete (and complex) example...

***myscript2.php***

```
<?php
$var = '{%%DEFAULT VAR%%}';
$varb = 'another string with DEFAULT VAR inside just to test';
print $var;
```

**Download script (called by the form)**

```
<?php
$form = 
'<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <span>myVar</span><input type="text" id="var" name="var"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="download file"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>';

if (isset($_GET['var'])) {
    $var = $_GET['var'];
    $path = 'myscript2.php';
    $file = file_get_contents($path);

    // PART 1   
    /*
     * Tokenizer Approach (read http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php)
     * Splits a php file into an Array with tokens (like the ZEND Engine Parser does)
     * Usefull for parsing and validating the PHP file
     * In this case we're just cheking if the script has
     * $var = {%%DEFAULT VAR%%}; somewhere but you can implement a more complex code to check 
     * complete statements or instructions!!! This is just for example's sake!
     * Skip this part if you don't need to validate the script
     */
    $tokens = token_get_all($file);
    if (!validatePHPScript($tokens)) {
        throw new Exception("script didn't pass validation");
    }
    //END PART 1

    // PART 2
    /*
     * The actual string replacement via str_replace
     * It actually just replaces a placeholder for anything
     * you want, in this case the $_GET['var'] value
     * You can actually replace a placeholder for a complete
     * block of code: just put the placeholder in the part you want
     * to insert and then comment it. #{‰‰PLACEHOLDER_NAME%%}
     * Then replace the placeholder with the comment tag
     *   
     */
      $file = str_replace('{%%DEFAULT VAR%%}', $var, $file);
    // END PART 2

    //PART 3
    /*
     * Serve the file to download through headers
     */
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myscript.php');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    print $file;
    // END PART 3

} else {
    print $form;
}
```

---

***validation function example:***

```
//Validation example
function validatePHPScript(array $tokens)
{
    $max = count($tokens);

    $var_check = false;
    $operator_check = false;
    $string_check = false;
    $semicolon_check = false;

    // loop through all $tokens
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; ++$i) {
        // only look for variables (tokens with type T_VARIABLE)
        if (is_array($tokens[$i]) && $tokens[$i][0] === T_VARIABLE) {
            // LOOK for a variable named $var
            if ($tokens[$i][1] === '$var') {
                // Found $var
                $var_check = true;

                // let's check if its an assignment statement
                // by looping through the remaining code until we find a colon
                for ($ii = $i +1; $ii < $max; ++$ii) {
                    // Look for the operator =
                    if ($tokens[$ii] === '=') {
                        $operator_check = true;

                    // Look for the string and check if it corresponds to the value
                    // we're going to replace
                    } else if ($operator_check && is_array($tokens[$ii]) && $tokens[$ii][0] === T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING && $tokens[$ii][1] === "'{%%DEFAULT VAR%%}'") {
                        $string_check = true;

                    // Look for the statement end token (semicolon) 
                    } else if($string_check && $tokens[$ii] === ';') {
                        $semicolon_check = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // All checks passed so we don't need to loop anymore
                if ($var_check && $operator_check && $string_check && $semicolon_check) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // reset checks
                    $var_check = false;
                    $operator_check = false;
                    $string_check = false;
                    $colon_check = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! You taught me how to do something I feel I'm going to use a bunch!